# Magento show latest products from a Manufacturer

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to get the latest 3 products from a specific manufacturer. The place I'm trying to do this is a product page, so I've to find what manufacturer the product is associated with and display the latest products.

Here's the code I got so far, it works but displays random products depends on the number I put in `->addAttributeToFilter()`.

Is `->addAttributeToFilter()` actually able to filter manufacturers? If not, what else should be used to make it work?

```
<?php $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    //->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 23)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=> 'manufacturer', 18)))
                    ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))                   
                    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->setPage(1, 3); ?>


<?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product) : ?>

<li class="arrowksleeper">
  <div class="menugridprodcont">
    <div><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(170, 100); ?>" alt="" /></a></div>
    <div id="menugridprodtitle"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a></div>
  </div>
</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

addAttributeToFilter works by passing the attribute name, and then an array describing how you want to filter it (except when instead of an array you pass `'null'` or `'notnull'`).  You probably want something more like this.

```
addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => 18));
```

Full Working code.  This assumes that '18' is a valid attribute for manufacturer.  You can actually get these by inspecting the form for Catalog->Attributes->ManageAttributes->Manufacturer->Labels.

```
$col = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq'=> 18))     
                ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                ->setPage(1, 3);
```

Comment: I've also tried that before, but nothing, it was getting me random stuff

Comment: Well it isn't wrong.  So something else is amiss here.  BEFORE the foreach can you echo or error_log `$_productCollection->getSelect();`?  Then you can see how the SQL is actually being run and spot why it is random.

Comment: $_productCollection->getSelect(); before the foreach will do you no good ti won't have assembled the query at the point.

Comment: Andrew, you are incorrect.  ->getSelect() will build the query based on the previous filters, selects, orders etc.  Try adding `echo $col->getSelect();` after my above code.  You will get a string (SQL) that looks like this.  `SELECT 'e'.*, 'at_manufacturer'.'value' AS 'manufacturer' FROM 'catalog_product_entity' AS 'e' INNER JOIN 'catalog_product_entity_int' AS 'at_manufacturer' ON ('at_manufacturer'.'entity_id' = 'e'.'entity_id') AND ('at_manufacturer'.'attribute_id' = '102') AND ('at_manufacturer'.'store_id' = 0) WHERE (at_manufacturer.value = 18)`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the report collection? That won't have the manufacturer attribute loaded, use the main product collection...

Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');

//$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
//     array('name' => 'manufacturer', 'eq' => 'ibm'),
//));

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => 99));
$collection->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
$collection->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(5); // first 5 products..

foreach($collection as $product) {
    // ..
}
```

Comment: I was using that because with product collection it doesn't work, unfortunately.. in fact you script give a 500 error `ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: attribute in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 314`

Comment: Lol I didn't even notice he wasn't using 'catalog/product'

Comment: try changing your own to use catalog/product collection not the report collection

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to Andrew and Jared for spending their time trying to help me. Unfortunately the scripts they provided wasn't working for ME (that doesn't mean that their script won't work for you) so I'm also posting below, how I managed it to work.

In order to work the script below should be placed in `app/design/frontend/default/YOUR-THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php 
$manuId = $_product->getManufacturer(); // getting manufacturer's id

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq'=> $manuId)) // $manuId: printing manufacturer's id
                    ->setVisibility(array(2,3,4))
                    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->setPage(1, 3); ?>

<?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product) : ?>

  <div>
    <div><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(170, 100); ?>" alt="" /></a></div>
    <div><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a></div>
  </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```